# nodeJS using NPM modules in external script files

Tags: node.js, npm, showdown

I am working on a markdown converter application, and using an NPM package showdown. In my app.js file I have a 
`var showdown = require('showdown');` 
which is properly being added. 
In my front end I require a script.js which needs to use this. However, it doesn't recognize the showdown variable. The code works perfectly if I use the showdown cdn above where I include my script.js. How do I make it so that my NPM modules can be used across a project?

Comment: Isn't it obvious Iza? Front end and backend code can't connect with one another.

Comment: So if I want to use an NPM package in my project (ie showdown, or showdown-katex) in my project how can I do this? There are some packages that I want to use without a CDN, so I need to require them as packages and use them in my script files.

Comment: is your project on git? It would have been great if I could have a look.

Comment: I also want to make the markdown downloadable, which requires another NPM module to be used.

Comment: Did it served the purpose? I have added download option for markdown. Have a look at the code. @Iza. An upvote and acceptance of the answer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your answer. I have forked your git repo and made changes.